# Discrete math, Combination question regarding pizza toppings and drinks

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My attempt:

The number of ways to order a pizza with 0 toppings: c(10, 0) = 1

The number of ways to order a pizza with 1 toppings: c(10, 1) = 10

The number of ways to order a pizza with 2 toppings: c(10, 2) = 45

The number of ways to order a pizza with 3 toppings: c(10, 3) = 120

The number of ways to order a pizza with 4 toppings: c(10, 4) = 210

For one pizza it would be: 1+10+45+120+210 = 386, so for 3 pizzas it would be 386 * 386 * 386 = 57512456 ways, i dont know how to equate for the drinks though. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You seem to have deleted the question you answered.  For the benefit of future readers, you should include the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drinks is just $5^3$.  (5 choices for the first, five chooses for the second...)

Comment: Would the answer be 57512456 * 5^3 = 7189057000 total possibilities?

Comment: Yep (assuming your calculations are correct; your reasoning is sound.)  It's usually okay, even preferred, to leave your answer in uncalculated form.

Comment: But what if the question were up to 25 out of 100 toppings?  Surely that's too much to actually calculate one at a time (even with a calculator)?